# How to bulk import ESRI projections into Postgis

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

Where can I get a file that would allow me to bulk upload all of the ESRI projections into the spatial_ref_sys table of postgis. I know that you can get insert statements on spatialreference.org; however one must look these up one by one --and I would rather just load them all at once.

Answer (score 3):

**A pretty dusty old answer**: Back in [version 0.8.2 (from 2004), `spatial_ref_sys.sql`](http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/tags/0.8.2/spatial_ref_sys.sql) was a colourful table with 563 definitions from ESRI, 1221 from EPSG, and one from BC (it was initially developed in Victoria, British Columbia.) The table was regenerated for later releases with only `auth_name = 'EPSG'`. The data can be merged with an existing table by first loading it into another table with identical schemata (e.g., `spatial_ref_sys2`), then:

```
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys(srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text)
SELECT srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text
FROM spatial_ref_sys2
WHERE srid not in (select srid from spatial_ref_sys);
```

which adds 473 'ESRI' definitions (not 563, as some have the same SRID codes as EPSG).

On a related note, I recall seeing an ESRI-specific `spatial_ref_sys` extra data with zigGIS years ago.